# Поиск подстроки в url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Получить текущий url страницы, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
И нужно проверить есть ли там подстрока questions, если есть то закрасить body в зелёный, если нет то не закрашивать. Для этого пишу

```
url = document.location.href;
if(url.indexOf('/questions/')+1){
    $('body').css({'background':'red'});
}
```

Проблема в следующем, если я применяю данный код на любой другой странице, то и там красится всё в зелёный, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = document.location.href;

if(url.match(/questions/)){
    $('body').css({'background':'red'});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
url = document.location.href;
if(~url.indexOf('/questions/')){
    $('body').css({'background':'red'});
}
```

Comment: поясните пожалста по поводу знака ~

Comment: побитовый оператор НЕ '~' эквивалентен выражению -(n+1)

Comment: ели применить ваш код на разных страницах например как здесь https://jsfiddle.net/uw3mozhq/ то работать не будет, как исправить

Comment: Я не понимаю что там может не работать, там конструкция проста, в переменной URL у вас хранится  урл страницы в виде строки, если в строке есть подстрока, например '/questions/' то indexOf вернет ее позицию, иначе -1. На этом все, indexOf ничего не знает про url страницы  и тп.

Comment: неработает потому, что у меня несколько подобных проверок, а если используется ~, то он отменяет выполнение последующих подобных условий

Comment: Либо если вы хотите НЕ найти совпадение то просто поставьте инвертируйте результат побитового НЕ с помощью оператора НЕ !~url.indexOf('question')

Comment: неработает потому, что у меня несколько подобных проверок, а если используется ~, то он отменяет выполнение последующих подобных условий - Так вы весь код приводите, вы спросили как найти подстроку в строке, я ответил. я ж не знаю про остальные ваши проверки